# Semantic Issue: Incompatible pointer to integer conversion sending 'NSUInteger *' (aka 'unsigned int *') to parameter of type 'NSUInteger' 

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios4, nsarray

So I get this **warning** :

```
Semantic Issue: Incompatible pointer to integer conversion sending 'NSUInteger *' (aka 'unsigned int *') to parameter of type 'NSUInteger' (aka 'unsigned int')
```

Basically i am pulling in a JSON feed.. looping through it to match columns up with data, then place the data in an object to be used in a table row...

```
NSDictionary *js_result = [response JSONValue];

NSLog(@"This is the LIST: %@",[js_result objectForKey:@"LIST"]);
//  get columns
NSArray *columns = [[js_result objectForKey:@"LIST"] componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
//  get data
NSArray *rows = [[js_result objectForKey:@"QUERY"] objectForKey:@"DATA"];



NSUInteger *study_id_int = (NSUInteger *)[columns indexOfObject:@"STUDY_ID_DICOM"];
NSUInteger *study_desc_int = (NSUInteger *)[columns indexOfObject:@"STUDY_DESCRIPTION"];
NSUInteger *study_date_int = (NSUInteger *)[columns indexOfObject:@"STUDY_DATETIME"];
NSUInteger *modality_int = (NSUInteger *)[columns indexOfObject:@"MODALITY"];
NSUInteger *referring_physician_name_int = (NSUInteger *)[columns indexOfObject:@"REFERRING_PHYSICIANS_NAME"];
NSUInteger *patient_id_dicom_int = (NSUInteger *)[columns indexOfObject:@"PATIENT_ID_DICOM"];
NSUInteger *patient_name_int = (NSUInteger *)[columns indexOfObject:@"PATIENT_NAME"];
NSUInteger *birth_date_int = (NSUInteger *)[columns indexOfObject:@"BIRTH_DATE"];
NSUInteger *institution_name_int = (NSUInteger *)[columns indexOfObject:@"INSTITUTION_NAME"];
NSUInteger *study_recvd_datetime_int = (NSUInteger *)[columns indexOfObject:@"STUDY_RECVD_DATETIME"];
NSUInteger *image_count_int = (NSUInteger *)[columns indexOfObject:@"Image_Count"];
NSUInteger *patient_study_count_int = (NSUInteger *)[columns indexOfObject:@"PATIENT_STUDY_COUNT"];



StudyListRow *StudyRow = [[StudyListRow alloc] init];

for(NSMutableArray *i in rows)
{
    NSLog(@"ROW DATA: %@",i);
    StudyListRow *StudyRow = [[StudyListRow alloc] init];
    StudyRow.study_id_dicom = (NSString *)[i objectAtIndex:study_id_int];
    StudyRow.study_description = [i objectAtIndex:study_desc_int];
    StudyRow.study_datetime = [i objectAtIndex:study_date_int];
    StudyRow.modality = [i objectAtIndex:modality_int];
    StudyRow.referring_physician_name = [i objectAtIndex:referring_physician_name_int];
    StudyRow.patient_id_dicom = [i objectAtIndex:patient_id_dicom_int];
    StudyRow.patient_name = [i objectAtIndex:patient_name_int];
    StudyRow.birth_date = [i objectAtIndex:birth_date_int];
    StudyRow.institution_name = [i objectAtIndex:institution_name_int];
    StudyRow.study_recvd_datetime = [i objectAtIndex:study_recvd_datetime_int];
    StudyRow.image_count = [i objectAtIndex:image_count_int];
    StudyRow.patient_study_count = [i objectAtIndex:patient_study_count_int];



}
```

Each of the **StudyRow....** lines gives the warning.. and I have no idea why.. Ideas?

Comment: If you actually read the warning it tells you why - "sending 'NSUInteger *' (aka 'unsigned int *') to parameter of type 'NSUInteger'" i.e you are passing pointers instead of objects.

Comment: I did read the warning.. but being new to this all.. I read it as sending an NSUinteger to an NSUinteger..  I did not even notice the *...

Comment: Here's the real problem: You got a warning but started with the assumption that there is something strange about the warning. The initial assumption should be that there is something wrong with the code, and that the warning will tell you what is wrong.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Lines like this:

```
NSUInteger *study_id_int = (NSUInteger *)[columns indexOfObject:@"STUDY_ID_DICOM"];
```

Should be

```
NSUInteger study_id_int = (NSUInteger)[columns indexOfObject:@"STUDY_ID_DICOM"];
```

They are primitives, not pointers to objects (where you would need the asterisk to indicate just that).

Answer (score 5):

Should be NSUInteger varName, not NSUInteger *varName. They are primitives.